# C++ Switch Cases

Tags: c++

I was doing a quiz online based on the C++ switch statement. I came across a question and I have a fair understanding of how switch statements work but this one question made absolutely no sense to me. Can someone please explain?

[image: Screenshot!]

Why is the answer D and not C?
Is Case 2: the default case or what?
This quiz can be found at: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/quiz/quiz5.html

Comment: Find about "case fall-through".

Comment: you need a break for every case

Comment: @zr: No idea. Probably duplicate.

Comment: I'm guessing it's probally not a good question, but thanks for your help guys! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how this code behaves.

- `x` is equal to zero

  - so `cout<<"Zero";` is executed.
- Since there's no `break;` after it,

  - the second case is executed: `cout<<"Hello World";`

And since `cout<<"something";` doesn't add a newline after printing, they're printed as a single word.

Comment: That makes sense to me now :) Thanks! I can't believe i didn't realize this sooner.

Answer (score 1):

since there is no `break;` statements in each case, the code will fall-through from `case 0:` to `case 2:`.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ a `case` will "fall-through" if there is no `break` statement:

```
int temperature = 20;

switch(temperature)
{
  case 20:
    cout << "it's nice and warm";
  case 25:
    cout << "it's a bit hot";
    break;
  case 30:
    cout << "It's way too hot!";
    break;
}
```

This will print out:
`it's nice and warm` AND `it's a bit hot` because there is no `break` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Since, x=0. It matches the 2nd case i.e. (case 0: cout << "Zero"; ). But there is no break statement to break out of the switch statement, it executes next cases too. If you have other cases its gonna execute and stop only when it find break statement or reaches the end of the switch case.

Comment: Which _"loop"_ actually? `switch` isn't a loop.

Comment: My bad, thanks a lot for pointing out the mistake. I corrected it.